# TRUNCATE_EXISTING vs. OPEN_EXISTING+SetEndOFile

Tags: winapi, createfile

What is the difference between calling Windows’ CreateFile with TRUNCATE_EXISTING and calling it with OPEN_EXISTING and then calling SetEndOfFile?

The former is documented to require GENERIC_WRITE access right, and if I ask only for FILE_WRITE_DATA,  CreateFile fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

For the latter, FILE_WRITE_DATA is sufficient, both CreateFile and SetEndOfFile succeed.

Answer (score 3):

the `FILE_WRITE_DATA` is single access bit (2). when `GENERIC_WRITE` is generic access, which mapped in case files in `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` you can view definition of it:

```
#define FILE_GENERIC_WRITE        (STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE    |\
                                   FILE_WRITE_DATA          |\
                                   FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES    |\
                                   FILE_WRITE_EA            |\
                                   FILE_APPEND_DATA         |\
                                   SYNCHRONIZE)
```

so except `FILE_WRITE_DATA` also include `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES`, `FILE_WRITE_EA`, `FILE_APPEND_DATA` and `READ_CONTROL==STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE`. ( `CreateFile` always implicit require for `SYNCHRONIZE` )

if you got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` for `GENERIC_WRITE` but ok for `FILE_WRITE_DATA` this mean that you have `FILE_WRITE_DATA` access to file, but not have some additional access from `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE`. this is rarely case but possible.

but really all what you need for truncate file is `FILE_WRITE_DATA` access. this is error and very bad design of win32 api `CreateFile`.

for truncate file to zero size we can use or:

- [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with `FileEndOfFileInformation` (The
  caller must have opened the file with the `FILE_WRITE_DATA` flag set
  in the *DesiredAccess* parameter) or with
  [`FileAllocationInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232076.aspx) - this work on all windows
- [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539(v=vs.85).aspx) - very thin win32 shell over
  [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) but available from vista only. with
  `FileEndOfFileInfo` or `FileAllocationInfo`. note that in case we set
  [`AllocationSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364214(v=vs.85).aspx) to 0 -- file will be truncated to 0 size too.

  > The end-of-file (EOF) position for a file must always be less than or
  >   equal to the file allocation size. If the allocation size is set to a
  >   value that is less than EOF, the EOF position is automatically
  >   adjusted to match the file allocation size.
- the `SetEndOfFile` first call [`ZwQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) with
  `FilePositionInformation` (just after file handle opened it set to 0)
  and then use it ([`FILE_POSITION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_position_information)) for **twice** call
  [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with both `FileEndOfFileInformation` and
  `FileAllocationInformation`. obvious in this case we have 2 not
  needed extra calls to kernel. so this not efficient compare first 2
  ways.
- the `CreateFile` with `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` first open file and than
  call [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with `FileAllocationInformation` set
  to 0. but this call, how you view require extra access -
  `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` which really not need. need only
  `FILE_WRITE_DATA`. so this way is bad
- use [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) with `FILE_OVERWRITE`
  *CreateDisposition* - it in single call open file and set EOF to 0. by sense `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` must do this (use `FILE_OVERWRITE`
  disposition). but by unknown reason (i think this is bug) it use
  `FILE_OPEN` access with additional call to
  [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with `FileAllocationInformation`
- if we need not only truncate *existing* file but also create new
  empty file, if it yet not exist - the best use `FILE_OVERWRITE_IF`
  option or it corresponded `CREATE_ALWAYS` - this also open and
  truncate file in single call to kernel. or create new file

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167503/discussion-on-answer-by-rbmm-truncate-existing-vs-open-existingsetendofile).